# Remove input effects

Tags: html, css, input

I trying to remove `input` effects, to make `input` element flat. I want to remove this[image: 3D Effect], 3d effect on border. And this [image: onclick effect], remove "onclick" effect.

At `onlick` I tried to use:

```
input:focus {
  border: none;
}
```

But not, worked.

Comment: Use  `outline:none;` please

Comment: Your issue could be coming from `box-shadow` and not `border`. Please share more code such as CSS style and HTML. If you right-click the element and "Inspect" it, you will see what style has been applied to the element

Comment: input {
  background-color: #3b4252;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
* {
  color: #eceff4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
:host, :root {
  --fa-style-family-classic: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}
:host, :root {
  --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}
:host, :root {
  --fa-style-family-brands: "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
  --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
}

Comment: I don't see any "3d effect on border" with that, at least not in a Chromium-based browser on a Mac - https://jsfiddle.net/cfmv6tj7/ So please present a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: I'm using Firefox on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this style in your code and don't use border: none; style.

```css
            input:focus{
                outline: none;
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name">
```

Comment: It works for outline style but, 3D effect not gone.